# Metaweblog API support in Drupal

Tags: drupal, cakephp, xml-rpc, metaweblog

I've been working recently on a blogging client, that helps posting on different platforms. The client is developed under CakePHP. I've managed to get things working for WordPress, using Metaweblog API calls via XML-RPC.

I thought I'd use the same technique to get things done for Drupal powered websites. But it didn't work.

I'm using CakePHP & the IXR Library (http://scripts.incutio.com/xmlrpc/) to make my XML-RPC operations. Here's a sample of how I get categories for a WordPress powered website:

```
App::import('Vendor', 'XMLRPC', array('file'=> 'IXR_Library'));

$client = new IXR_Client('http://www.myblog.com/xmlrpc.php');
$client->query('metaWeblog.getCategories', '', $username,$password);

if(!$client->getErrorCode()) {
    $categories = $client->getResponse();    
} else {
    echo 'An error occurred : '. $client->getErrorMessage();
}
```

When using the same code for Drupal websites, I get:

> An error occurred : Server error. Requested method
>   metaWeblog.getCategories not specified.

Does it mean Drupal isn't supporting Metaweblog API? Do I need to install extra plugins on the Drupal websites?

Or, is there another way to remotely publish content on Drupal powered webites?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [here](http://drupal.org/node/295) Metaweblog is supported, but needs to be installed in Drupal - i.e. it is not 'out of the box'.